# Why do I get an AttributeError on a class, even though I defined a method with that name?

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, methods, attributeerror

I'm taking an "intro to object-oriented programming" class and I'm on chapter 17 of Think Python. The following code is stumping me.  I keep getting "AttributeError: 'Time' object has no attribute 'print_time'" when running it and I'm having little luck figuring it out.  Can someone help break down what I'm doing wrong and help explain it a little better for me?

```
class Time(object):
    """represents the time of day.  attributes: hour, minute, second"""

def print_time(time):
    print '%.2d:%.2d:%.2d' % (time.hour, time.minute, time.second)

start = Time()

start.hour = 9
start.minute = 45
start.second = 00

print_time(start)

class Time(object):
    def print_time(time):
        print '%.2d:%.2d:%.2d' % (time.hour, time.minute, time.second)

start.print_time()
```

I read that it was an indentation error but I have IDLE set to warn me for conflicts and have checked it twice to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's go through your code a step at a (cough) time.

```
class Time(object):
    """represents the time of day.  attributes: hour, minute, second"""
```

Here, you're defining a [class](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-class) `Time`. It has a [docstring](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-docstring), but no methods or other attributes.

```
def print_time(time):
    print '%.2d:%.2d:%.2d' % (time.hour, time.minute, time.second)
```

This is a [function](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-function), completely separate from the `Time` class you defined earlier, which accepts an argument `time` and tries to print a string using `time`'s `hour`, `minute` and `second` attributes. If `time` doesn't have all of those attributes, you'll get an error.

```
start = Time()
```

This creates a `Time` object called `start`.

```
start.hour = 9
start.minute = 45
start.second = 00
```

These lines add `hour`, `minute` and `second` attributes to `start`.

```
print_time(start)
```

This calls `print_time` with `start` as an argument, resulting in the output:

```
09:45:00
```

So far so good. Now ...

```
class Time(object):
    def print_time(time):
        print '%.2d:%.2d:%.2d' % (time.hour, time.minute, time.second)
```

This creates a **new** class, which happens to also be called `Time`. It doesn't have a docstring this time, but it does have a [method](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-method) called `print_time` (which is completely separate from the `print_time` *function* defined earlier, although it has the same name and code).

It's important to realise at this point that just because you've created a new class called `Time`, that **doesn't have any effect at all** on objects you created with the previously defined class. They're still instances of the *original* `Time` class you defined. It's easy to prove this with the builtin `help` function:

```
>>> help(start)
Help on Time in module __main__ object:

class Time(__builtin__.object)
 |  represents the time of day.  attributes: hour, minute, second
 |  
 |  Data descriptors defined here:
 |  
 |  __dict__
 |      dictionary for instance variables (if defined)
 |  
 |  __weakref__
 |      list of weak references to the object (if defined)
start.print_time()
```

Notice that `help` shows you the docstring from the original `Time` class, but not the method from the new version.

```
>>> help(Time)
Help on class Time in module __main__:

class Time(__builtin__.object)
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  print_time(time)
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data descriptors defined here:
 |  
 |  __dict__
 |      dictionary for instance variables (if defined)
 |  
 |  __weakref__
 |      list of weak references to the object (if defined)
```

... whereas this shows the `print_time` method from the new `Time` class, but not the docstring from the original one.

One way to think of this is that a class is like a factory that makes objects – and tearing down the Ford factory then building a new one in the same place doesn't have any effect on the '71 Mustang already sitting in your driveway.

If you want an instance of the *new* `Time` class, you'll have to create it:

```
>>> restart = Time()
```

... and then, once it has the right attributes ...

```
>>> restart.hour = 9
>>> restart.minute = 45
>>> restart.second = 00
```

... you'll be able to call its `print_time` method successfully:

```
>>> restart.print_time()
09:45:00
```

Comment: That was exactly what I needed to have comprehension of what I did wrong.  I got it to work after another 45 minutes debugging but now I have greater ability for the future. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't do Python, but I'm going to guess from the good error message that you are trying to call a method that doesn't exist for the object type.

This line (at the end):

```
start.print_time()
```

Should probably be replaced with something like this:

```
print_time(start)
```